# CocosBuilder adding files to existing project

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I have an existing CocosBuilder project and I wish to add an image (png) to it. I've tried adding the image in the projects directories but it doesn't show up in the project yet new directories do. Also tried dragging and dropping directly into the project.

Is this possible? Just can't seem to find a way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! My Image was named `background-568h@2x.png` and I removed the "@2x" and it was able to add it.